# react-router - access only given node params in getComponent()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use Route's getComponent() ( https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#getcomponentnextstate-callback ) to add some asynchronous logic to the routing. I got it mostly working but got stuck on how to only receive params related to current node fragment of the path.

An example:

```
const getSampleComponent = (nextState, cb) => {
  console.log(nextState.params);
  cb(null, () => {    
    return <div><Link to="/test/1">/test/1</Link> <Link to="/test/1/test2/2">/test/1/test2/2</Link></div>
  });
}

function createRoutes() {
  return {
    path: '/',
    getComponent: getSampleComponent,
    childRoutes: [{
        path: "test/:id",
        getComponent: getSampleComponent,
        childRoutes: [{
          path: "test2/:id",
          getComponent: getSampleComponent
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}


ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={createMemoryHistory()} routes={createRoutes()} />
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

( running version: http://jsbin.com/dedazozije/edit?html,js,console,output )

using `console.log(nextState.params);` I can list all the params, but those will contain params for the whole matched path, not only the node. So in case I visit /test/1/test2/2 it will be

```
[object Object] {
  id: ["1", "2"]
}
```

Reepated 3 times. I would like to only see:

- for / getComponent - an empty object
- for test/:id getComponent - `{id: 1}`
- for test2/:id getComponent - `{id: 2}`

Is that data provided somewhere or is parsing the path location and matching params to it the only way?

Comment: I wonder if `getComponent` is deprecated? The link to the docs above no longer exists...

Comment: @lucas this example was using react-router v3, the current master branch points to v4 thus the link is no longer valid - see https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#getcomponentnextstate-callback